# Google Analytics in Magento Upgrade 1 to 2

Tags: magento2, migration, google-analytics

Im trying to find out if its okay to use the same tracking ID from GA in Magento 2.

The customer has a magento 1.9 website now and im upgrading it to Magento 2. So, new website - same tracking codes? I cant find anything on Google Analytics migration on Magento.. Does anyone have any experience with this?

There's no events, and everything in GA is pretty much standard.. Is it ok to just use the same tracking IDs?

Comment: which code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracking IDs are tied to domains (properties), not your website software. So yes, it is fine (and expected, actually) that you use the same Google Analytics IDs on Magento 2 as you did for your site on Magento 1.

Comment: Great! Thanks =D So there should be no loss of data in Google Analytics?

Comment: Test to verify, but no, there should be no loss of data.